# RoR Hobo: Could not find table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, subclass, hobo

So I'm trying to add a subclass to one of my models and then create a fixture and test for it, but I seem to be running into errors along the way. I don't really know how to describe the problem, but I recreated it with the following steps. If you want me to add something to this question please ask.

Console

```
$ hobo new lab --setup
$ cd lab
$ hobo g model foo num:integer
```

IDE

```
#inserted into app/models/foo.rb
def do_foo
    num*5
end

#create app/models/bar.rb
class Bar < Foo
    def doo_foo
        num*10
    end
end
```

Console

```
$ hobo g migration
```

IDE

```
#create test/fixtures/bars.yml
bar_one:
  num: 1

#create test/unit/bar_test.rb
require 'test_helper'
class BarTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_bar
    puts Bar.first.do_foo
    assert true
  end
end
```

Console

```
$ rake test
```

ERROR

```
1) Error:
test_bar(BarTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'bars'
```

Comment: Have you created the DataBase? `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create` (eventually add a `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`)

Comment: I haven't yet. I posted everything I did.

So I would just type this into the console?

    $ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create
    $ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate

Comment: just the first command, which should create the database in your DBMS, the db:migrate will execute all migrations not referenced in the Schema table.

Comment: So apparently db/test.sqlite3 already exists, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out your fixture.
Since Bar is a Subclass of Foo it will use the Foos fixture.